# jQuery check element ID

Tags: jquery

I know there is plugin called .hasClass();

I have the following

`$('#page_background, #header_background').ColorPicker({...`

how would I check if page_background is clicked and not header_background?

This is what I have now, it won't work.

```
$('#page_background, #header_background').ColorPicker({
        onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
            $(el).val(hex);
            $(el).ColorPickerHide();

            var id = this.id;

            if(id == 'page_background')
                $('body').css("background-color","#"+hex);
        },
        onBeforeShow: function () {
            $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
        }
    })
    .bind('keyup', function(){
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor(this.value);
    });
```

Comment: you are looking for the id `background_color` however you aren't binding the click event to an element that has that id. (based on the edit that you just reverted i guess)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $('#page_background, #header_background').click(function(){

   var id = this.id;
   if(id == 'page_background')
     // page background
   else
     //header 
 });
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vGJdc/)

As you are using this inside colorpicker `onSubmit` function

```
onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
```

where you get the element as `el`, so to get the `id` use

```
 var id = $(el).attr('id');
 // or
 var id = $(el).prop('id'); // new way
 //or simply
 var id = el.id; // this should work too
```

Comment: Check the fiddle and click on any text.

Comment: it says this.attr is not a function

Comment: Weird :s Which browser are you using? It's working fine for me.

Comment: it works fine for me with your example, but when I put mine it won't work

Comment: In you case use `var id = $(el).attr('id')`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a reference to the clicked element stored in `this`, you can simply use the native DOM property:

```
var id = this.id;
```

If `this` is a jQuery object, not a DOM node, you can use `this.attr("id")`.

Also note that `hasClass` is a normal jQuery method, not a plugin. It's part of the standard jQuery library.

Comment: ... or `prop("id")` as well (in new versions).