# Zurb Foundation 6: Trigger event when accordion menu opens?

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation 6 Accordion menus. How can I trigger a JQuery function when an accordion item opens? I think it might have something to do with down.zf.accordionMenu, but I haven't found any examples.

I found out from [this post](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/50459244.shtml) that I can test if any of the accordion menus are open, but what if I only want to test when a specific item opens? Here is the code for all of them:

```
jQuery('#id_of_accordion').on('down.zf.accordion', function() {
  //run code here
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the element as second parameter from your listener.

See https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.accordion.js#L282

```
this.$element.trigger('down.zf.accordion', [$target]);
```

https://api.jquery.com/trigger/
[image]

See the documentation for the handler at https://api.jquery.com/on/
[image]

Take a look at the console when you use this code:

```html
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
  <li id="accordion-1" class="accordion-item is-active" data-accordion-item>
    <!-- Accordion tab title -->
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 1</a>

    <!-- Accordion tab content: it would start in the open state due to using the `is-active` state class. -->
    <div class="accordion-content" id="accordion-content-1" data-tab-content>
      <p>Panel 1. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <a href="#">Nowhere to Go</a>
    </div>
  </li>
   <li id="accordion-2" class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
    <!-- Accordion tab title -->
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accordion 2</a>

    <!-- Accordion tab content: it would start in the open state due to using the `is-active` state class. -->
    <div class="accordion-content" id="accordion-content-2" data-tab-content>
      <p>Panel 2. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <a href="#">Nowhere to Go</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

```js
$(document).foundation();

$('[data-accordion]').on('down.zf.accordion', function(event, element) {
  console.log(element);
  if($(element).attr('id') === 'accordion-content-2') {
    console.log('accordion 2 opened');
  }
});
```

See the codepen at https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/OJNPWog

Comment: thank you for looking at this. I guess I'm a noob because I still don't quite understand. In my example, if i want to test for "tab2", would the function look like:
jQuery('#id_of_accordion').on('down.zf.accordion', [jQuery('#tab2')], function() {
  //run code here
});
Also, what code would go after that? When I try this, I don't get errors, but I still get a result whenever the accordion opens instead of only when tab2 opens.

Comment: I have updated myanswer and added an example code so you just have to check what you see in the browser console. In general it should be a jQuery object (the element).

Comment: The [] brackets mean optional in docs and the first parameter in the handler (the anonymous `function()`) is always the event, after this come all extra parameters passed to `trigger()`.

Comment: Wow. I'm sorry to be so dense, but I'm not understanding. You are correct that your example func returns the accordion object and displays info about the tab I clicked, but I still don't understand how to only test if "tab2" was clicked. As it is now, all of the tabs still return an answer. 

I added your func to my live page and left the console.log. It shows the results like this: [div#opcert.accordion-content ... In this live version, it's the div#opcert that I'm interested in listening for. I want to know when it finishing opening.

https://deq.utah.gov/drinking-water/payment-portal

Comment: This is expected, You did not provide any code example in your question so I could not provide a clear answer. In general you have to check the element in the nonymous function with checks like `$(element).attr('id') === 'opcert'` which is basic jQuery. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885477/jquery-check-element-id. If your check returns true you want to do execute the needed logic.

Comment: By the way, the website does not load for me here in Germany. Questions should always contain the needed code snippets and clearly state what is needed. I will update the answer. The answer should now include a working example so you can see how it works.

Comment: Again, thank you. I will do better at using Codepen or similar instead of live examples. It didn't occur to me that my example was geoblocked. Sorry.